# CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/CoreOnly": React native firebase

Tags: firebase, react-native, cocoapods

Upon trying to update my pods to the latest in order to work with IOS 12.0 I keep getting this error. I've seen this error pretty well documented online but none of the current solutions I have found seem to work.

```
  In Podfile:
    RNFBApp (from `../node_modules/@react-native-firebase/app`) was resolved to 10.5.0, which depends on
      Firebase/CoreOnly (~> 7.4.0)

    RNFBAuth (from `../node_modules/@react-native-firebase/auth`) was resolved to 10.5.1, which depends on
      Firebase/Auth (~> 7.4.0) was resolved to 7.4.0, which depends on
        Firebase/CoreOnly (= 7.4.0)

    react-native-camera/BarcodeDetectorMLKit (from `../node_modules/react-native-camera`) was resolved to 3.42.0, which depends on
      Firebase/MLVisionBarcodeModel was resolved to 5.0.0, which depends on
        Firebase/CoreOnly (= 5.0.0)
```

As far as `pod install --repo-update` and `pod update` etc I keep returning to this error. I've updated my dependancies manually in the package.json file to the latest and removed the `pod.lock` file. I've run a react native clean across it to ensure all cache files are cleaned and tried to reinstalling everything and still getting the error.

I'm sure I'm missing something that I either need to wipe somewhere but can't find where exactly I need to do this.

Here's my Pod file

```
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

platform :ios, '12.0'

target 'shoppinStore' do
  config = use_native_modules!

  use_react_native!(:path => config["reactNativePath"])

  target 'shoppinStoreTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  # Enables Flipper.
  #
  # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
  # you should disable these next few lines.
  use_flipper!
  post_install do |installer|
    flipper_post_install(installer)
  end
end

target 'shoppinStore-tvOS' do
  # Pods for shoppinStore-tvOS

  target 'shoppinStore-tvOSTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end
end

# add the Firebase pod for Google Analytics
pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
# add pods for any other desired Firebase products
# https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#available-pods

pod 'react-native-camera', path: '../node_modules/react-native-camera', subspecs: [
  'BarcodeDetectorMLKit'
]
```

And my Package.json

```
  "name": "shoppinStore",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/checkbox": "^0.5.7",
    "@react-native-community/geolocation": "^2.0.2",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^10.5.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^10.5.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/firestore": "^10.5.1",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.11.3",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.0",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.13.0",
    "firebase": "^8.2.3",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "0.63.4",
    "react-native-camera": "^3.42.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.9.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.13.2",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.1.9",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.16.1",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.3",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.2",
    "redux": "^4.0.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.4",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.8.4",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^1.1.0",
    "babel-jest": "^25.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.5.1",
    "jest": "^25.1.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.59.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.13.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

I'm pretty new to React Native, this all happened after chasing errors trying to connect my phone to test the app to get the React Native Camera library to work. Not the project won't build at all. Any pointers will be greatly appreciative.

Comment: Also getting this

Comment: I discovered the problem, it's down to the `BarcodeDetectorMLKit` part of pod file. Once this was removed it was ok, however... I haven't found the fix yet as I still need the Barcode element to work....

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem due to M1 chip.

1. I deleted Pods folder
2. Deleted PodFile.lock
3. For M1 chip :

   ```
   1. Install ffi
   ```

> sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi

```
    2. Re-install dependencies
```

> arch -x86_64 pod install

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this also so I updated my firebase packages in package.json, deleted podfile.lock in the ios folder, and ran pod repo update, then pod install.

Worked after that! Good luck!

Comment: similar issue but this didn't help me